# How do I match cells in one column to another, considering multiple conditions?

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I want to match my record of the daily sales deposit transactions (multiple deposits in a day from multiple branches) with my bank account transaction history which i download online. The purpose of this sheet is to verify if the sales deposits were indeed credited into my account.

Cells in columns A to C are "copy and pasted" from an online bank statement, while cells from columns D to F are "copy and pasted" from a separate excel file made by another staff.

```
Transaction date(A1) | Transaction Type(B1) | Amount(C1) | Sales Date (D1) | Source(E1)   | Date Deposited (F1) | Amount(G1)   
6-3-13(A2)           | Cash Deposit(B2)     | $20(C2)    | 6-2-13(D2)      | Branch 1(E2) | 6-3-13(F2)          | $60(G2)  
6-3-13(A3)           | Check Deposit(B3)    | $50(C3)    | 6-2-13(D3)      | Branch 2(E3) | 6-3-13(F3)          | $20(G3)  
6-3-13(A4)           | Cash Deposit(B4)     | $60(C4)    | 6-3-13(D4)      | Branch 1(E4) | 6-3-13(F4)          | $80(G4)  
6-3-13(A5)           | Cash Withdrawal (B5) | $80(C5)    | 6-3-13(D5)      | Branch 2(E5) | 6-3-13(F5)          | $50(G5)  
(blank) (A6)         | (blank)(B6)          | (blank)(C6)| 6-3-13(D6)      | Branch3(E6)  | 6-3-13(F6)          | $50(G6)
```

Since cell G2 is found among cells C2 to C6 then H2 should say "DEPOSITED." The same is true for G3 and G5. G4 and G6, on the other hand, are not found on the bank's transaction history, therefore, it should say "MISSING" in H4 and H6.
Note that columns G and C should only be compared when A=F and when B= Cash or Check Deposit. C5 is not counted since B5 says the transaction is a withdrawal.

Comment: Sounds to me that there's something missing logically. Are you sure you have all the information necessary to do this analysis?

Comment: consider adding a comment instead of an answer specially if you are not providing an answer rather asking a question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a verbose but hopefully readable implementation:

```
Sub check()
    Dim bankRange As Range
    Set bankRange = Range("A2")

    Do While Not IsEmpty(bankRange)
        Dim transType As String
        transType = Trim(bankRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
        If transType = "Cash Deposit" Or transType = "Check Deposit" Then
            Dim bankDate As Date, bankAmount As Double
            bankDate = bankRange.Value2
            bankAmount = bankRange.Offset(0, 2).Value2

            Dim sellRange As Range
            Set sellRange = Range("F2")
            Dim matched As Boolean
            matched = False
            Do While Not IsEmpty(sellRange)
                Dim sellStatusRange As Range, sellStatus As String
                Set sellStatusRange = sellRange.Offset(0, 2)
                sellStatus = sellStatusRange.Value2

                If sellStatus <> "DEPOSITED" Then
                    ' By default consider not matched
                    sellStatusRange.Value2 = "MISSING"

                    Dim sellDate As Date, sellAmount As Double
                    sellDate = sellRange.Value2
                    sellAmount = sellRange.Offset(0, 1).Value2

                    If matched = False And sellDate = bankDate And sellAmount = bankAmount Then
                        sellStatusRange.Value2 = "DEPOSITED"
                        matched = True
                    End If
                End If

                Set sellRange = sellRange.Offset(1)
            Loop
        End If
        Set bankRange = bankRange.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

It simply goes through the bank deposits and marks the next matching sell as "DEPOSITED".

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA you need a few helper columns.  First add a column `E` and put this formula in it `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Deposit",B2),0)>0,CONCATENATE(A2,"_",C2),"")`.
The `FIND` clause will detect if it is a deposit or not.  If it's not a deposit then it won't use that entry.

Next in column `H` add this formula `=CONCATENATE(G2,"_",H2)`.

Now you have a single column on the input side and a single column on the output side each with the pieces of information you want to compare.

In column `J` put in this formula `=VLOOKUP(I2,$E$2:$E$6,1,FALSE)`.  It will search through the E column for something that matches the value.  In column `K` use this formula `=IF(I2=J2,"Deposited","Missing")`.

**Edit:**
Different approach to better account for multiple instances of same deposit.

First insert a column `E` and use this formula `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Deposit",B2),0)>0,CONCATENATE(A2,"_",C2),"")`

This column puts the date and amount together whenever it is a deposit.

Create column `I` with `=CONCATENATE(G2,"_",H2)`

Create column `J` where the first row will be `=IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$6,I2)>0,"Deposit","Missing")`

For the next row of column `J` use this formula `=IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$6,I3)-COUNTIF(I$2:I2,I3)>0,"Deposit","Missing")`  and copy it down.  The new formula will deduct any instances in the prior rows so that it won't double count transactions.

Comment: this follows your methodology which has what seems like a bug where your bank only acknowledges one deposit of $50 on 6/3 but there is a deposit on your side from both branch2 and branch3.

Comment: If I understand well this is precisely this kind of anomaly the OP wants to detect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dean MacGregor! If I have two deposit transactions in column H with the amount $20 and there is only one transaction with that amount in column C, it would still appear as "DEPOSITED" for both the transactions. How do I correct that? Also, the word "missing" does not appear if my record of the deposit does not appear in the bank transaction history. Instead "#N/A" appears. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @J.M.Neri New methodology to account for double counting.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you Dean! You're an excel genius!